# Regex to extract first word after last colon without space and with full match

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have to do **Full Match** for a word which comes after the last colon and between spaces. e.g. In below Sentence

`XYZ Cloud : ABC : Windows : Non Prod : Silver : ABC123XYZ : ABCdef Service is Down`

Here I have to do full match for **ABCdef**. `([^:.*\s]+$)` returns **Down**, `([^:]+$)` returns ' **ABCdef Service is Down**' as full match. However I am looking for **ABCdef** as full match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match until the last occurrence of `:`, then match a spaces and capture 1+ non whitespace chars in group 1.

`^.*: +(\S+)`

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*: +` Match any char except a newline as much as possible followed by 1 or more spaces
- `(\S+)`  capture **group 1**, match 1+ times a non whitespace char followed by a space

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WJITG0/1)

For a match only, you might use a positive lookarounds:

```
(?<=: )[^\s:]+(?=[^\r\n:]*$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=: )` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is `:
- `[^\s:]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or `:`
- `(?=[^\r\n:]*$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is at the right it 0+ times any char except a newline or `:` and assert the end of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qWSuRw/1)

Comment: It's not coming as a full match:(. I tried both, that's the problem I have, it should come as a full match.

Comment: @Vishal What do yo mean by full match? What is the tool or language? Like this perhaps `(?<=: )[^\s:]+(?=[^\r\n:]*$)` https://regex101.com/r/qWSuRw/1

Comment: Thanks, it works:). It will be great for all of us , if you can decode it a bit.

Comment: @Vishal I have added an explanation about the pattern parts

Answer (score 0):

Using C#, this works:

```
var text = @"XYZ Cloud : ABC : Windows : Non Prod : Silver : ABC123XYZ : ABCdef Service is Down";
var regex = new Regex(@":(?!.*:)\s(.+?)\s.*$");

Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(text).Groups[1].Value);
```

I get:

```
ABCdef
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest `[ ]*([^: ]*)[^:]*$`

- `[ ]*`: any amount of spaces
- `([^: ]*)`: a group with the target non-space word with no colons
- `[^:]*$`: the rest of the line without colons

https://regex101.com/r/LMQrb7/1

---

To access the word you're looking for, use group 1.

Comment: Did you see the number of steps?

Comment: I'm not sure what your are asking.

Comment: If you click on the regex101 link, at the right top you see the number of steps. It is quite large, because all the quantifiers are optional.

Comment: No guarantees about the text was given, so I choose a more reliable regex. The only optimization I see is `[ ]*([^: ]+)[^:]*$`. I would only do that if a performance issue was demonstrated.